# How will blockchain handle cloned nodes?

Tags: nodes

What happens if a server contain fully synced ethereum node is clone and started, how will the blockchain handle cloned instances ?

Cloning the OS disk image, and running it on a different physical server, and maybe different network. assuming we are using go geth in full syncing mode.

Comment: Do you mean the whole disk(s) (OS, applications, data) is cloned and put into an identical machine? And do you mean both machines are running at once (and the node software)? What node software? What is the network configuration you're envisioning? And are the nodes doing anything in particular or just connecting to the blockchain and syncing?

Comment: @lungj I added the details you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'll assume you aren't going to run into OS licensing issues and can boot straight in and that you've handled any network issues.)

You should have two nodes that stay in sync with the network and can serve requests. You shouldn't notice any differences/problems for the configuration you've described. The new machine will have many of the same peers as the first one, which may be undesirable, because it will have the same peers list. I've forked VM disk images with no trouble with `geth` (pre-DAO). You may need to delete the `nodekey` file on the "new" machine (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3n25w5/what_is_ethereumnodekey/)); I've always done this, so I don't know what happens if you don't (probably nothing terrible).